# Impossible to remove ^I ending from a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file with this ending:

```
line1^I$^M$
line2^I$^M$
line3^I$^M$
```

I have trying many options I found in the web by using `sed` command and even 'dos2unix' but they only work to remove the `^M$` but not `^I`. So my file is now like this:

```
line1^I$
line2^I$
line3^I$
```

I have scrutinized in the web but there is nothing about `^I`. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: `^I` is a literal tab character.

Comment: How are you producing that output? If it's `cat -A`, how do you have 2 line ending `$` chars in the output?

Comment: A note to readers, use `printf "line%d\t\r\n" 1 2 3 > file` to create this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your file will look like this using `od` or `cat -A`

```
$ od -c foo
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  \t  \n   l   i   n   e   2  \t  \n   l   i
0000020   n   e   3  \t  \n
0000025
$ cat -A foo
line1^I$
line2^I$
line3^I$
$
```

To strip *all* `^I` (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) characters, you could use `sed -i 's/\t//g' foo`.  To *only* strip tabs at the end of a line, used `sed -i 's/\t$//' foo`

```
$ sed -i 's/\t//g' foo
$ od -c foo
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  \n   l   i   n   e   2  \n   l   i   n   e
0000020   3  \n
0000022
$ cat -A foo
line1$
line2$
line3$
$
```

Comment: To my knowledge, `\t` for TAB is only supported by GNU `sed`. Better use a literal tab instead (usually entered by preceeding it with ctrl-V). This should work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`^I` is probably not indicating a caret followed by an I, but rather is a representation of the character composed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.  This character actually has a shortcut on most keyboards, to wit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  If you were to `cat` the file, you would probably see something like:

```
line1    $
line2    $
line3    $
```

Unless, that is, whatever you're using that is displaying literal `^I`s is also showing the end of the line with a visible `$`.

You can use `tr` to eliminate them if you like, though:

```
$ cat file | tr -d '\t'
```

`\t` in this case is a magic sequence that is an easy way to represent a Tab character in several common tools (including, helpfully, `tr`).

<sub>`dos2unix` did nothing to the Tabs because they are identical between all the platforms that tool is used to "translate" to and from.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried `cat file | tr -d '\t'` but the `^I` is still there, I can see it when I use `cat -A file.txt`

Comment: That's because `cat -A` is _what you use_ to make tabs and EOLs visible.  The `cat` command will replace the contents of the file and display it _to_ you.  To make a new file without tabs, use `cat file | tr -d '\t' > newfile`.

Comment: Ooh! I got it, that is in the case to make a new file.  I didn't know `^I` is another form to represent a tab.  Knowing that, now I have tried with `sed` as @steve suggested and it finally gone.  Thanks